# Running Powershell Script

Tags: sonarqube

We have a third party software that is ran via a Powershell script once it has ran it it retuns results back via the script (as well as an XML files).

My question is there anyway within Sonar Qube to run a Powershell script (or windows command line) or would I have to write a brand new plugin?

Russell

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what the 3rd party tool is, or what kind of results it yields. So at a guess: yes, you'll have to write a new plugin to read the results generated by this tool and import them as part of your analysis.

Notice, I don't mention firing the tool. That can be done, but in general plugins simply import tool reports, and because plugin development is done in Java, it is likely to be simpler to include kicking the tool off as part of your build script/process. However, if you feel you really must fire it from your plugin, the [StyleCop plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-stylecop/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/stylecop/StyleCopExecutor.java) may point you in the right direction. But while the StyleCop plugin fires StyleCop directly, you'll be firing a script to fire your tool. Or maybe you'll be incorporating your script logic into your plugin...? (Probably fewer headaches in the long run that way.)

Comment: Just to confirm the tool is internal legacy tool that will not mean much if I put it here.  The Powershell script will if finds a problems return an error code and output the error to stream.  As said tool also outputs to XML file the format is custom XML format.

Hope that helps.  Also out of interest firing the tool how can this be done etc?